# Hyperlinking text in django which sends to an email

Tags: python, html, django, email

I would like to make "click here" a hyperlink which when clicked, would send people to 127.0.0.1 for example.

```
 confirm_links = 'To confirm this order <a href= "127.0.0.1://confirmorder/" > click here </a> '
```

I think this would normally work, but I am having the code be sent through email.

Comment: Check the above link - Basically, you can design the template the way you want..

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

or

Do you want something like this?

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/

Comment: I've already got this code implemented. It already sends the user an email. I am trying to figure out how the text can be activated as a hyperlink when sent through email.

Comment: Err. I'm hoping to get the body of the text to hyperlink. Not the title